# Java how to rearrange numbers inside a String

Tags: java, string

```
String str1 = "11,22,13,31,21,12";
String str2 = "11,12,13,21,22,31";
```

Is there a simple clean way to modify str1 to get str2?

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you can't modify str1. You can only assign a new String to it.

Comment: Split, sort, merge?

Comment: Simple clean way? `str1=str2` HAHA

Comment: @PeterRader no sorry that was not my intention, str2 is the result. Assigning str2 to str1 is quite meaningless, sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: Who voted to close as being "too broad"? Although not a very useful question and not showing some effort, this question is short and clear. It does not deserve an upvote, though.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose for me, it looks like no one voted "too broad - unsalvageable". I voted for "Requires editing", see comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Java 8 solution with a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
String str2 = Stream
    .of(str.split(","))
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .sorted()
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(joining(","));
```

Note: For the `joining` method I have a [`import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-).

The interpretation as a number (`Integer::parseInt`) is important, as this will correctly sort the input.

Comment: I voted up because it handles numbers like `9` correctly.

Comment: @PeterRader Yes, this is usually important, so I added a comment to make it explicit.

Comment: Well, the main difference is: other values.

Comment: Obviously the question lacks some information about the nature of those values. But I think by looking at the string we can safely induce that the string contains only numbers (till proven wrong).

Comment: where "joining" method?

Comment: @Jerry06 A static method in `Collectors`. I edited the answer.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes sir my title implies that they are numbers ,  and I would like to ask what does the joining mean at the last line thanks

Comment: import static worked :), Eclipse did not suggest that

Comment: @securenai I edited my answer by linking some useful information into it.

Comment: @Jerry06 I have added the class `java.util.stream.Collectors` as a favorite: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Favorites. By doing so, you also get its methods as a suggestion.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose thank you sir, I will read into this simple solution

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then I think you wanted to rearrange in ascending order

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "11,22,13,31,21,12";String str1[]=str.split(",");

        Arrays.sort(str1);
        for(String s:str1)
        {
            System.out.print(s+" ");
        }
    }
```

**output:** 11 12 13 21 22 31

Comment: Hmmm ... Although working, it is not exactly what OP asked for. 1) He wants to have the _output_ in a new variable. 2) The delimiter should still be a comma (which introduces a new problem when doing it your way). Maybe you can optimize your answer to a pre-Java-8 solution?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Intentionally I did not complete the answer as OP will not learn anything. I have It op's work to replace the space with comma(,) and store in a separate variable. 50% I have completed and 50% left for OP

Answer (score 0):

Check below code and comment:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "11,22,13,31,21,12";
        StringBuffer strB = new StringBuffer();
        String[] arr = str.split(","); // Split string save in array
        Arrays.sort(arr); // sort array
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  //add array in stringbuffer
            if (i != arr.length - 1) {
                strB.append(arr[i] + ","); 
            } else {
                strB.append(arr[i]);
            }
        }

        String str2 = strB.toString();
        System.out.println(str2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple snippet, gives exactly what you've asked :-

```
    String[] splitData;
    String str1 = "11,22,13,31,21,12";
    System.out.println("str1 : "+str1);
    String str2 = "11,12,13,21,22,31";
    splitData =  str1.split(",");
    Arrays.sort(splitData);

    System.out.print("str2 : ");
    for(int i=0; i<splitData.length; i++){
        if(i!=(splitData.length-1))
            System.out.print(splitData[i]+",");
        else
            System.out.print(splitData[i]);
    }
```

Output:
run:
str1 : 11,22,13,31,21,12
str2 : 11,12,13,21,22,31